# Is there an std:: implementation of the cummulative min

Tags: c++, gcc

so suppose

```
float bar [5] = {  5.7106, 3.1768, 5.7458, 4.5859, 2.2718 };
```

I'm looking for a function such as:

```
cummin(bar,bar+bar.size());
```

that would return the in-place cummulative minimum of the 
entries of bar, e.g. have that bar contains:

```
5.7106, 3.1768, 3.1768, 3.1768, 2.2718
```

my question is also wether it's possible to implement the 
cummulative min more efficiently than the naive approach 
(it's used in a bottleneck function in a code I'm working
 on and I don't think it can be vectorized).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s no such function. However, this is an application of [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), which is known as [`std::partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) in C++.

You could call it like this:

```
std::partial_sum(begin(bar), end(bar), begin(bar),
    [](float a, float b) { return std::min(a, b); });
```

If this is still a bottleneck, then an interesting observation is that the prefix sum can be efficiently parallelised. This isn’t quite trivial. Luckily, parallel algorithms libraries such as [Threading Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) already contain implementations of it.

Comment: Do you have any link on how to efficiently parallelize this ? It seems to me than the value of `out[i]` is inherently dependent on the values of `in[0:i]` so that I see how to parallelize writes but not computations.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You can independently calculate intermediate results on a wave front. The Wikipedia article linked in my answer contains a section explaining this briefly. [This Guy Blelloch paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf) is the seminal work on prefix sum implementations.